# Regular expression substring for labelling

Tags: qgis, labeling, regular-expression

I downloaded OSM .pbf raw data for Germany. Right now I'm trying to create label badges for german highways. German highways have names starting with the letter 'A' followed by a number with up to three digits.

In my dataset the information about the highway name is stored in a column called "other_tags" alongside with other information looking like this:

```
"bdouble"=>"yes","maxspeed"=>"none","oneway"=>"yes","ref"=>"A 7","surface"=>"asphalt"
```

I want to extract the 'A 7' diregarding the rest of the string. I thought about using regular expressions to do so (QGIS actually has this feature -> GREAT!), however I'm stuck implementing it without failing.

This is what I've tried using a custom expression for 'Label with':

```
regexp_substr( other_tags ,'A\s[0-9]+')
```

My understanding of the regexp implementation is:

`regexp_substr('string to analyze', 'regular expression output')`

However, since that does not work I could need some help on building the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `regexp_substr( "other_tags" ,'(A\\s[0-9]{1,3})')` (tested on QGIS 2.14).

The key part are the parentheses `()`, corresponding to the capturing group.

<s>For some reason, `\s` does not seem to work, so I replaced it with a simple blank space.</s> As per ndawson's comment, `\s` simply needs to be escaped (`\\s`).

I also replaced `[0-9]+` with `[0-9]{1,3}` to fit your criterion ("names starting with the letter 'A' followed by a number with up to three digits").

Comment: the "\" in "\s" needs to be escaped - replace it with "\\s" and it'll work.