# Using substring for labeling in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

I read [Regular expression substring for labelling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213308/regular-expression-substring-for-labelling)

and it got me curious.  I'm trying to do something similar with OSM content in QGIS.

I would like to label features with English names if those names are stashed in the `other_tags` attribute.  If English names do not exist in the `other_tags` attribute field, fall back to the `name` attribute.

I've gotten only as far as finding whether an English value exists:

`"other_tags" LIKE '%"name:en"=>"%'`

Perhaps someone could explain to me how to put all this in a conditional check within QGIS, calling the `name:en` value to be rendered as the label, and if the conditional check fails, use the `name` field.

I am on QGIS 2.14.

**UPDATE:**

I read through [QGIS Multiple CASE WHEN/THEN Statements for Expression Based Labels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162297/qgis-multiple-case-when-then-statements-for-expression-based-labels)

and it does not answer my question.  I am not concerned with how to take multiple attributes and stack them in a label.  I am looking at a single attribute field in OSM called `other_tags`.  The structure of this tag looks like this:

`"name:ar"=>"[some arabic text here]","name:ru"=>"[some russian text here]","name:en"=>"Gaziantep"....etc...`

What I'm trying to do is take, for example, `Gaziantep` out of `"name:en"` out of the overall `other_tags` field.

I can use CASE expression to roll over to the regular `name` field if the conditional check fails, but how do I syntactically obtain the `"name:en"` subvalue?

Comment: You can use a CASE statement - see if this answer addresses your problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162297/1297 then it can be closed as a possible duplicate

Comment: I think I may have spoken too soon.  This link does not answer my question.  This shows how to do conditional labeling based on an entire attribute - I'm trying to seek through a single attribute field in OSM (the dreaded "other_tags" attribute) and find a substring, and then find `n` number of characters in that string until another delimiter.

Comment: am I getting this wrong...can´t you just select any tag with flags (name::en) when exporting to spatiallite?

Comment: @ThingumaBob I would like to keep all features in my view, naming those with `name:en` tags with that, and then if that doesn't exist, name it with whatever is in the `name` field.  And even if I did that, I'm still left with the same labeling question, because it's not putting that `name:en` value into its own attribute field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work - it was taken and adapted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63339/1297

```
regexp_substr(right("other_tags", length("other_tags")-(strpos("other_tags",'"name:en"=>')+10)),'([^"]+)')
```

It will split the `"other_tags"` field at `"name:en"=>` and then remove the first 11 characters, essentially stripping out the `"name:en"=>` from the string. That's what the `+10` is for.

So it would go from 
`"name:en"=>"some english name","name:fr"=>"some french name",...` to
 `"some english name","name:fr"=>"some french name",...`

So next is to then use the regular expression `([^"]+)` to extract only the string it finds in the first set of double quotes, but without the double quotes.

The regular expression will take `"some english name","name:fr"=>"some french name",...` and return `some english name`.

So to put that as a CASE statement, use:

```
CASE WHEN "other_tags" LIKE '%"name:en"=>"%'
THEN regexp_substr(right("other_tags", length("other_tags")-(strpos("other_tags",'"name:en"=>')+10)),'([^"]+)')
ELSE "name"
END
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this with just the `regexp_substr()` function without having to split the field with the nested `right()`,`length()`,`strpos()` functions but I'm quite elementary with the regular expressions.

A more simplified answer would be welcome - would help me learn more too!

Comment: Quite elementary? I'd say your regex-fu is pretty darn good.  This gave me *exactly* what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I still might not get if these are the tags you are looking for, but when I download OSM data (for the region of Gizantep since you named it, via QGIS native OpenStreetMap-Dataloader [*Vector -> Opnstreetmap -> Download data... -> Import topology from XML -> Export to SpatialLite*]) and select the tag `name` and all tags with `name:xx` flag in the tag selector window, the exported and loaded layer attribute table from spatiallite include columns for each of them. When I use
`CASE WHEN "name:en" IS NOT NULL THEN "name:en" ELSE "name" END`in the label settings, I think I get what you want?

(-> all Labels (`name:en`) in english if present, otherwise standard names (`name`), I somehow can´t seem to include my screenshots here...)

EDIT:
Now, after @SaultDon's answer it finally hits me: it's all in one column. I leave this here in case you will end up importing data via the plugin ,)