# Regular expression to extract road labels from OSM other_tags ref

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling, regular-expression

Extended question to the issue: [Regular expression substring for labelling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213308/regular-expression-substring-for-labelling/266420?noredirect=1#comment423166_266420)

The answers I've found on the link above were fine for "simple" road labels.

Unfortunately, I don't have a big SQL-knowledge, therefore, I would like to extend Erik's question. 
How can we extract other road labels (alphanumeric) from the OSM lines layer "other_tags" between the ("ref"=>") and the last (")?

Examples:

1. "ref"=>"AP 520" -> AP 520
2. "ref"=>"M123-4" -> M123-4
3. "ref"=>"EN 13-5" -> EN 13-5
4. "ref"=>"AG-52" -> AG-52

In order to avoid to write thousands of different expressions depending on each example, isn't any expression that extracts the content only of "ref"=>"**xxxxxxxx**"?

I tried everything using the "regexp_substr".

Comment: Can you post how the tag looks in the database.  I would like to see how the quotation marks work in it.  If you had a string String = ''' "ref"=>"AP 520" ''' and you wanted to only get 'AP 520' you would do ,  NewString = String.split(' " ')[-2] , that would give you 'AP 520' for the NewString.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
regexp_substr("other_tags",'"ref"=>"([\\w- ]+)')
```

Should work assuming you have no other kinds of whitespaces, or unusual symbols/letters in the ref field.

It looks for `"ref"=>` then matches any word characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscore) as well as dash and space (`[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]`) and continues doing so (`+`) until it stops matching (in this case when it hits the double quotation mark).

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
regexp_substr( "other_tags", '\\"ref"=>"(.*?)\\"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open your OSM file with the QuickOSM plugin. It will split your "other_tags" into fields automatically.
If the process is too slow, you can provide a custom OSM Conf file to get the field you want in QuickOSM, "Open OSM file" tab.